# On Lubkin's works on p-adic cohomology

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am curious to know what the things are going after Lubkin's several works on p-adic cohomology. As Math.Sci.Net shows, his papers on this topic have a few citations despite of the titles which sounds captivating. I would appreciate it if someone would explain how the things going after his works.

Best regards,
TY

Comment: Whereof one cannot speak, thereof one must be silent.